# ng-change isn't firing on select in Foundation for Apps

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

On a Foundation-for-Apps web application, I want to trigger a function in my controller when a select value is changed.

I did the following in my template:

```
---
name: meeting-rooms
url: /meeting-rooms
controller: MeetingRoomsCtrl
animationIn: slideInRight
animationOut: slideOutLeft
---

<div class="custom-tabs" zf-tabs="">
    <div class="custom-tabs-item" zf-tab="" title="Location" data-options="one_up: false">
        <form class="form">
            <select id="selectLocation" class="select form-place-select" ng-model="selectLocation" ng-change="selectLocationChanged()">
                <option value="">Select a place</option>
                <option value="New York">New York</option>
            </select>   
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And  my controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('application').controller('MeetingRoomsCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope, $state, $window, foundation, ModalFactory, NotificationFactory) {
            $scope.selectLocationChanged = function() {
                console.log($scope.selectLocation.name);
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Which is supposed to work: the `ng-model` is provided, the function `selectLocationChanged` exist in the scope (I can use other variables set in the controller in the same template), and the syntax `ng-model="selectLocation" ng-change="selectLocationChanged()"` is correct. I don't have any error message in the console, the change event is just not fired.

Is there any reason why this is not working? Maybe something specific with Foundation For Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this, forgot to include controller in HTML page

```
<form class="form" ng-controller="MeetingRoomsCtrl">
     <div  >
      <select id="selectLocation" class="select form-place-select" ng-model="selectLocation" ng-change="selectLocationChanged(selectLocation)">
           <option value="" disabled="disabled">Select a place</option>
           <option value="New York">New York</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: I tried, with no success. Anyway the `selectLocation` should be accessible through the scope, and even if I do a simple `console.log('test')` in the function it is just not get call.

Comment: @vard can you pls change the value to ng-value

Comment: Just tried it, it just throw errors because the value isn't a valid angular expression. I will give it a try with `ng-options` and see if it help then.

Comment: pls run the code snippet it is work, I think problem is in your app

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same as in the snippet, it just doesn't work and doesn't throw any error. I think this is related in some way with Foundation.

Comment: can you remove the form-place-select class from select

Comment: It doesn't help, event still not fire.

Comment: pls check you add the controller name in the root of the element

Comment: In foundation you don't need to use `ng-controller` to include the controller, it use the `controller:` property at the top of template file - see the top of my template. It is well included because I can access other variables / functions from that controller in the same template.

Comment: I found it out!! You put me in the right way, it was indeed a controller problem: when you use the tabs in foundation, it seems that even if you're in the scope of the controller you need to include it again at the tab level. Putting ng-controller on the form solved the issue! If you can edit your question to reflect this I will accept it, thanks for your assistance.